# In stata, how to bring down the first value on y axis to the base of the graoh?

Tags: label, axis, yaxis

I would like to bring down the first value on y axis "10" to the base of the graph. I have had to repeat this graph for several antibody subtypes and there have been no issues; always the first value in my y label code is at the base.

Here's a picture of the graph that's giving me trouble:
[image: Graph Example]

And a screenshot of my code:

[image: Code Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can change the range of an axis by adding the following option to your twoway command:

```
yscale(range(1 4))
```

This should limit the range from 1 to 4 in logscale. See documentation [here](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/g-3axis_scale_options.pdf).

However, note that `range` will not work if it would result in cutting off the data. I don't know what your data looks like but if `range` does not have the expected result, see discussion [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1467591-how-to-change-the-scale-of-the-y-axis-in-bar-graph).